# How to loop through date range using selenium on a website with 15 days range?

Tags: python, selenium, date, iteration

I'm automating data collection from a website which allows only 15 days range. My goal is to get data from 2016 till date. To do this, I am using selenium. How can I make a loop using selenium to gather data within the start and end date?

I am able to achieve the desired result by copy-pasting the code block 60 times and changing the date range to get 30 months worth of data. But I am looking to make my code more efficient and smaller by introducing while loop.

```
#removing information from date range
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_mainScreen_mmDealSearchDealDetails_daterange_dIFrom"]').clear()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_mainScreen_mmDealSearchDealDetails_daterange_dITo"]').clear()

#putting From and To date
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_mainScreen_mmDealSearchDealDetails_daterange_dIFrom"]').send_keys('01/05/2019')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_mainScreen_mmDealSearchDealDetails_daterange_dITo"]').send_keys('15/05/2019')

#clicking on search button
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_mainScreen_btnSearch4"]').click()

#clicking on Download ALL button
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_mainScreen_DealsSummaryComplex_ExtendedResultsToolbar1_lbReportAll"]').click()

#clicking on Download button under Personalised Reports Section
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_mainScreen_ctl01_btnDownload"]').click()

sleep(30)

#switches to download window
browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[1])

#clicks on download deals option
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_popupScreen_lblClickHere"]').click()

#closes download window
browser.close()

#clicking on Last Search Tab
browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[0])
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_pageHeader"]/header/nav/div/ul/li[2]/a').click()
```

This section of the code is being repeated 30 times with every code block having a different start date and an end date (line 6 and 7). Could anyone help me out with this please?

Comment: Is it a public website?

Comment: @supputuri No, it is a business website which requires login.